# Dynamically assign values in CSS

Tags: css, primefaces

Is it possible to position a link or text dynamically based on the content present above.

For example, I have a page as follows:

**Dashboard.xhtml**

```
<div id="innerContainer">            
<p:dataTable id = "adminDataTbl" value="#{userAdminMB.userRoles}" var="userList" selectionMode="single" selection="#{userAdminMB.selectedUser}" rowKey="#{userList.ntId}" styleClasses="order-table,table" headerClass="order-table-header" rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" >                     
    <p:column styleClass="table-data">  
        #{userList.ntId}
    </p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="table-data">  
        #{userList.roleList}
    </p:column>                 
</p:dataTable>
</div>

<div id="userLink">
    <h:commandLink action="#{userAdminMB.addUser}">
            <h:outputText value="Add a User to the Admin Tool"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```
#outerContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px; 
    top: 150px;
    border: 1px thin;
}

#innerContainer{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 9px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px thin;
}

#addUserLink{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    top: 550px;
    position: inherit;
}

.editUserLink-data{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: right;
    top: 175px;
}
```

The data in `<p:dataTable>` may be different based on the DB hit that is made. I need the addUser link to be positioned accordingly.

Please help. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Css is not a dynamic language, use PHP or Javascript.

Comment: Would you like to stack them on top of each other?

Comment: Give us some HTML code.

Comment: I'm confused at the use of the word dynamic here.

Comment: You need to read something about css, for your example simple DIV(s) with right styles will do the trick. Also if you dont alter content after page is rendered(like with some javascript/ajax or so), dont call it dynamic, its just confusing.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: I hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: @Gatekeeper : Please check the edited question, I have defined more of my question I hope.

Comment: @soyuka : Thank you for the suggestion but I cannot use php here. Javascript on the other hand, if you could give me an example, it would be helpful.

Comment: @sciFi: where do you want your link to be exactly? Why do you have "float: left;" style on innerContainer? Best solution would be some working example on jsFiddle... then we can help you much faster ;)

Comment: @Gatekeeper : Thanks for the heads up on `float:left;` that was unnecessary. But jsFiddle? Um, if you could give me link pointing to it, it'd be really helpful.

Comment: @sciFi look at http://jsfiddle.net/ its very usefull tool to share html/css/js code, just past it there, make some adjustments to it to work there, save it and share link... its so cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly then what you want to do is:

```
 <div sytle="textalign: right" id="firstLink">Link1</div>

 <div id="dynamicContent">
     dynamic content here
 </div>

 <div id="link2">Link2</div>
```

If you want to add relative positioning between the dynamicContent and link2 divs you can do so.

Using the above code the link two will fall below the dynamic content on your page

Comment: Thank you, but if you could give me a solution to the edited question, it would be really helpful. I have used `<div>` as suggested.

Comment: what do you mean by positioned accordingly? Where in accordance to the center div do you want the link to appear? If the div is directly below the main content div then it will always appear below the main content.

Comment: Actually the content inside the data table keeps differing based on the db hit, hence the link gets placed below with a lot of white space in case of lesser values inside. That's what I meant. Any help?

Comment: Are you populating the Data Table with strings or a mixture of different data?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get a solution to it. It was because of the div after all. Thanks :)